# Trying to scrape Canon Webpage using selenium

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

One of the categories has Load More button which load cameras. I need to write function that scrolls to Load more button and clicks it
url: https://www.usa.canon.com/shop/cameras/mirrorless-cameras

```
def find_load_more(driver, xpath):
    try:
        return WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
        )
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout waiting for the load more button.")
        return None


def scroll_to_load_more(driver, xpath):
    print(xpath)
    try:
        load_more_button = find_load_more(driver, xpath)
        if load_more_button:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", load_more_button)
            load_more_button.click()
        else:
            print("Load more button not found.")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("The 'Load More' button does not exist.")


def scrape_canon_preview(category, driver):
    url = f"https://www.usa.canon.com/shop/cameras/{category}"
    driver.get(url)
    wait_for_page_load(driver)
    # Click Load more to load all the cameras
    scroll_to_load_more(driver, "//button[@class='primary amscroll-load-button']")
```

But It returns Load more button not found and Timeout waiting for the load more button.